# Problem when I try to add some php extension on my M1 mac

Tags: macos, sqlite, homebrew, php-extension, libav

After trying to install the sqlite extension, I can no longer run php on my mac. I keep getting brew errors.

Has anyone had a similar problem?

```
dyld[58991]: Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/libavif/lib/libavif.15.dylib
  Referenced from: <87C1A268-34E4-396F-8BBC-D5591064E333> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gd/2.3.3_5/lib/libgd.3.dylib
  Reason: tried: '/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/opt/libavif/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/opt/libavif/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/opt/libavif/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/usr/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libavif/1.0.1/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libavif/1.0.1/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libavif/1.0.1/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/usr/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
```

I follow other issues as this one but nothing fix my pb

Answer (score 32):

To fix this issue, you need to install or reinstall GD

```
$ brew install gd
```

or if you have already gd installed, run

```
$ brew reinstall gd
```